# Lotus notes 8.5

Tags: lotus-notes

so I'm new to lotus notes, and this question is probably over kill since i am just a user, and don't administer the server, but in another questions it was suggested to try running fixup. so i started googleing fixup and found this statement

"Keep in mind that after you set up transaction logging, Fixup is not needed or used to bring databases back to a consistent state."

so I can't help but wonder why you wouldn't need something to fix a corrupted database if transaction logging is set? this suggests that transaction logging keeps databases from becoming corrupt. is that what transaction logging does? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

No, this says that if you enable transaction logging you have **better and more reliable method** of restoring your database to consistent state than to run fixup (namely, log reply) *if it become corrupt*

It's very clearly described in [Transaction Logging on Domino Servers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003543):

> Transaction logging provides three main benefits:
>
> - In most situations, you no longer need to run the Fixup task to recover databases following a system failure. Excluding Fixup results in quicker server restarts, since Fixup must check every document in each database, while transaction log recovery applies or undoes only those transactions not written to disk at the time of the system failure.
> - Transaction logging saves processing time because it allows Domino to defer database updates to disk during periods of high server activity. Transactions are recorded sequentially in the log files, which is much quicker than database updates to random, non-sequential parts of a disk. Because the transactions are already recorded, Domino can safely defer database updates until a period of low server activity.
> - Using transaction logging simplifies your daily backup procedure. You can use a third-party backup utility to perform daily incremental backups of the transaction logs, rather than perform full database backups.